# Select column and row values with an index in data frame

Tags: r

I have a matrix of correlations, and I am trying to keep the maximum value (considering absolute values) of each pair (row/column). I wanted to ask, how to extract the values if I have the index of the position with the specific max. value. 
This is my sample:

```
mat <- structure(c(0, 0.428291512801413, 0.124436112431533,    -0.345870125921382, 
             0.391613957773281, 0.428291512801413, 0, 0.341415068127906, -0.346724601510298, 
             0.486360835614514, 0.124436112431533, 0.341415068127906, 0, -0.496213980990412, 
             0.41819049956841, -0.345870125921382, -0.346724601510298, -0.496213980990412, 
             0, -0.80231408836218, 0.391613957773281, 0.486360835614514, 0.41819049956841, 
            -0.80231408836218, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("LO3","Tx", "Gh", "RH", "SR"), c("LO3", "Tx", "Gh", "RH", "SR")))
```

Then, I am taking the index of maximum value:

```
ind <- apply(abs(mat), 2, which.max)
```

which gives me:

```
LO3  Tx  Gh  RH  SR 
2   5   4   5   4
```

What I wanted now, it's getting the value of these position for each column ..
which would be:

```
LO3       Tx        Gh
0.4282915 0.4863608  -0.4962140 .....
```

I tried to use `apply`, but I don't know how to do it..or if there would be another way to do that.

Comment: Just `mat[cbind(1:nrow(mat), ind)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have your indices in `ind` one way could be to use `mapply`:

```
#the first argument is the function call 
#second argument is your matrix coerced to data.frame
#third argument is your indices
#each time an index will be used in conjunction to a column
#and you get your result
mapply(function(x,y) x[y], as.data.frame(mat), ind)
#       LO3         Tx         Gh         RH         SR 
# 0.4282915  0.4863608 -0.4962140 -0.8023141 -0.8023141
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works perfect!

Comment: You are very welcome @user3231352 . Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

This can do it for you:

```
mapply(function(i,j) sample[i,j], seq_len(ncol(sample)), ind)

> mapply(function(i,j) sample[i,j], seq_len(ncol(sample)), ind)
[1]  0.4282915  0.4863608 -0.4962140 -0.8023141 -0.8023141
```

if you want you can set the names of the result from `ind`